# Getting fields from JSON using Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-resource

This is a very simple question but I'm writing a webpage that's supposed to display the user's information. There will be fields of name, id, role, etc. I want to write setter and getter methods for the JSON that I receive from the database. For example, if I get a JSON and I want to get and display the name field, how would  I write this getter method in angularJS after getting the JSON from a $resource service?

This is an example of how the JSON would look:

```
[{"name": "Jason"
  "date of birth": "february 23, 2985"
  ....
 }]
```

Again, I just want to know how to write a getter method if I wanted to get the name field.

Answer (score 3):

Should be just like javascript.

```
var result = [{"name": "Jason"
  "date of birth": "february 23, 2985"
  ....
 }];

var firstResultsName = result[0].name;
```

But i noticed a problem with the result that you gave. You need a comma after each property.

```
[{"name": "Jason", <<-- this comma is necessary to work correctly.
"date of birth": "february 23, 2985",  <<-- and this one.
```

make sure you have commas for all but the last property.